# Libchart (PHP chart) - same image?

Tags: php, graph, render

I am using LibChart. It works fine, however, i have an issue. I'm not sure it is directly linked to the library, more of a general php/image thing that i am maybe missing.

Thing is, the image doesn't update itself (the image that contains the graph) unless i re-upload the PHP file that draws it. This is how the graph is made, using LibChart

```
$chart->render("generated/demo4.png");
```

That renders it into that file, and i display it using

```
<img alt="Line chart" src="generated/demo4.png" style="border: 1px solid gray; float: right;"/>
```

It works great, but only the first time it is drawn. It won't redraw the image unless i re-upload the file that draws it. That is kinda bad, since it draws data from a database, and when that changes it needs to be reflected in the graph.

What might be the issue? 
How can i redraw the image without re-uploading the file?

Comment: Maybe some cache trouble?

Comment: Yes that is what i am thinking, but i am very new to this, so how can i fix it? :P

Comment: The cache is in every case a trouble, there are questions with long post on StackOverflow that will teach you that doesn't exists a code unique. You need to use some cache code for a specified browser to make it works.

Answer (score 1):

Which internet browser are you using?
Some of them (for example IE) are storing images in internal memory (for faster rendering the web site). You can save the rendered graph in file, then load it again in variable and finaly this variable show as base64 data.

```
$path = "tmp/graph.png";
$chart->render($path);
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
return "<img src=\"data:image/".$type.";base64,".base64_encode($data)."\" />";
```

It is a bit weird, but it worked for me. Now I am looking for some better solution.